# is there a book overviewing different types of source code metrics?

Tags: code-metrics

I have to submit a paper about the usage of source code metrics in software engineering processes.  I thought it would be nice to start by introducing some categorization of source code metrics  (for example using plane LOC count Vs doing some static analysis of the code) , but I can't find a book or article that will present the different types of metrics and possibly some historical background information (books and article are favored by my instructor over web sites).

any one knows of such a source ?

Comment: Well .... there is most likely a book on *everything*...

Comment: are code metrics really that useful? It seems software development changes faster than the metrics...

Comment: so now that we've established the book existences can someone name it ?

Comment: Mitch: that is one of the conclusions I have to draw from my paper

Comment: @Mitch Yes, they are. I run complexity metrics on my code to look for trouble spots where refactoring is needed.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: you don't know where your own code needs refactoring without metrics?!?

Comment: @Mitch Not all the code that is "mine" was written by me.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Prevention is better than cure. ;)

Comment: Complexity metrics can also help quantify which spots in your code are in more immediate need of attention.  They can scan and summarize the code base much faster (even if a bit less accurately) than you can.

Comment: @ Bill the Lizard: That's right, and like most averaging processes they tend to lose something.

Comment: Also see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9975340/19501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressman's [Software Engineering: A Practitioner's Approach](http://www.rspa.com/sepa7e.html) has a lot of good information on software metrics (among other things).

Probably the key piece of advice on metrics is to be careful what you measure.  If you measure LOC, that's what people will concentrate on.

> "Not everything that can be counted counts, and not everything that counts can be counted."
>
> --Albert Einstein
>
> "Measuring software productivity by lines of code is like measuring progress on an airplane by how much it weighs."
>
> --Bill Gates

Comment: never heard that Bill Gates quote before. good one

Comment: @Mitch: One of my favorites.  It's such a perfect and concise analogy.  Much better than his (probably more famous) quote about how much memory anyone will ever need. :)

Comment: Apparently, he denies ever making the latter...

Comment: @Mitch: I hadn't realized that, but apparently he denies it very strongly. http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bill_Gates#Misattributed

Comment: Bill the Lizard: Thank you for suggesting this book, it is exactly what I was looking for.  it was literally right in front of my face,   on the shelves in front of the the desk I am currently working on -:))

Comment: @Kent: Wow!  I mean... uh... yeah, I knew it was there the whole time. ;)

Comment: Actually, Gates is off-base on that one.  EVERYONE who has ever worked for an airplane company knows that an airplane is NEVER ready to fly until the documentation (drawings, plans, manuals, you name it) weighs more than the airplane does.  Airplanes are COMPLEX systems, and there are no shortcuts to engineering them.

Comment: you mean like the Airbus that's in production with the software control fault?

Answer (score 2):

Patrick Smacchia's [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) site has a good set of definitions: [Metrics Definitions](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx). His NDepend tool (for .NET) provides many different ways of quantifying a codebase.

How useful metrics are, well that is a bit more contentious. They are good for getting a sky level view of a codebase, but are they useful day-to-day? How many shops out there use (or care about) metrics on a weekly basis? I suspect most are more concerned with the bug count: number of bugs fixed and number of bugs reported.

Certainly measures like cohesion and coupling give indicators of possible refactoring points.

Another important metric: How many tests are there, and roughly how much code coverage do those tests represent. Refactoring without tests and good test coverage is a risky business.

[Software metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_metric)

[Code Metrics Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx)

Comment: thx for those punishment votes sam

Answer (score 1):

### Metrics and Models in Software Quality Engineering


Stephen H. Kan

[image]

Not always very fun to read, but it's an excellent book that covers software quality and metrics **in depth**.

Answer (score 0):

Halstead's ["Elements of Software Science"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444002057) was the seminal work in this area.  As I recall the tale, he defined some 15 different metrics, all purporting to measure different qualities of a piece of code.

Unfortunately, [van der Meulen & Revilla](http://www.ecs.csun.edu/~rlingard/comp589/HoffmanArticle.pdf) showed that a couple of key metrics are very strongly correlated with SLOC (source lines of code).  (This was not the first time this had been demonstrated, but it was the first paper I could find quickly.)  Since SLOC is far easier to measure than the other things, SLOC is what should be measured - and managed.

Comment: Halstead's book struck me as pure pseudo-science.  He talked about a "software physics" and came up with equations that purported to compute things like "Effort" from source code.  I don't believe it was tied into any empirical measurement.  So I'm with your second reference on that.

Answer (score 0):

[PSP: A Self-Improvement Process For Software Engineers by Watts S. Humphrey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321305493)

Answer (score 0):

Also check [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/). This is not a book but a set of tools for counting physical Source Lines of Code. Going through its [user manual](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/sloccount.html) and the papers in the site about the usage of SLOCCount for estimating Linux kernel size will give you insight about effectiveness of SLOC metrics,issues in using it as metric, usage of SLOC metric in the COCOMO model for effort estimate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a book, but the metrics used by [Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) offer a good list of practically useful code metrics. Here's the [metric definitions](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions) page.

Answer (score 0):

As I just mentioned in [my question on visualizing changes in metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869928/how-can-i-visualize-changes-in-a-large-code-base-quality), there are the books [Object-Oriented Metrics:Measures of Complexity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132398729) by Henderson-Sellers and the earlier [Object-Oriented Software Metrics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013179292X) which I've owned for years.

There's [Metrics and Models in Software Quality Engineering, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201729156), the only one of the books [available on Safari](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-201-72915-6) which has a [chapter](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-201-72915-6/ch12lev1sec2) discussing the above metrics and some industry results.

I also just found a 2006 book [Object-Oriented Metrics in Practice: Using Software Metrics to Characterize, Evaluate, and Improve the Design of Object-Oriented Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540244298) which has no reviews there (not a good sign) but sounds interesting.